# Prevent access to UIViewControllers with tab bar controller (storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I currently encountering a problem with my iOS application.
I am attempting to incorporate a gradual login pattern, i.e.: the use can access some of the app without being required to login.

Required features are as follows:

- At all times the user can view all navigation items that require login
- When the user attempts to access an uiview(controller) that requires login, they will be prompted with a UIAlertView asking them to log in. (Preferably the UIAlertView will appear when the app recognised the initiated segue destination is restricted).

At first I used a subclass of UIViewController that, in the designated initialiser (initWithCoder), would check NSUserDefaults to see if the user was logged in. I then subclassed off of that. Limitations were as follows:

- Couldn't use other subclasses of UIViewController, namely UITableViewController
- The UIAlertView came up after the view had appeared, which i am assuming would cause errors if the subclassed UIViewController assumed the user was logged in.

**Question summary:**
I would like to know how to conditionally prevent users from accessing certain UIView(Controller)s and subclasses of UIViewController, and when that happens present a UIAlertView.

**Update 1**
Could categories and/or protocols be a viable solution?

**Update 2**
CodaFi pointed out singletons as a great solution to manage the user's state.

With that implemented I now need to figure out how to control the user's access.
As I am using storyboards I feel that the most versatile implementation would be subclassing UIStoryboardSegue, and on the perform method check if the user is attempting to access an restricted UIViewController (perhaps restricted controllers have a protocol property that specifies the required status: logged in/out). However the pitfall here is that you cannot choose the class/subclass of a UIStoryboardSegue in the storyboard graphic editor. I am aware that I could do it programatically, however that seems tedious as i would have to add IBActions and like that to methods that perform segues, furthermore I don't think that would work with the way elements such as navigationController and tabbarControllers behave.

*Does anybody have a viable solution to restricting the user's navigation?*

**Update 3**
I've added an answer to this question, however I still deem it as unanswered because the answer I've written doesn't take into account segues between navigation bar controllers. However it may help some people.

Comment: Could a singleton work?  A sort of gatekeeper singleton class that would manage your defaults across the application.

Comment: What @CodaFi said plus using the delegates of UITabViewController and UINavigationController.

Comment: I haven't heard the term singleton before, after doing some WikiResearch i figure you mean some kind of state keeping object? Also, I'm using storyboard, could extending UIStoryboardSegue be a solution?

Comment: Singletons are very popular in iOS programming

Comment: Wow looking back on a time when I didn't know what singleton was. Singletons may be popular. But they are bad practice / an anti-pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I've answered how to do this using custom segues.

Now I understand my real problem was the mental disconnect with the tabbarcontrollerdelegate protocol.

As a solution to preventing access to tabs I've made a class to handle said tab bar controller

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TabBarDelegate : NSObject<UITabBarControllerDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>{
    UITabBarController *cachedTabBarController;
}

@end

#import "TabBarDelegate.h"

@implementation TabBarDelegate

-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
    NSLog(@"Pretending the user isnt logged in");

    if(true){
        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You require an account to access %@",viewController.tabBarItem.title];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Account Required" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles: @"Login",@"Create Account",nil];
        [alert show];
        //Hold tabbarcontroller property for alert callback
        cachedTabBarController = tabBarController;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(cachedTabBarController){
        switch (buttonIndex) {
            case 1:
                //Login
                [cachedTabBarController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tabBarToLogin" sender:cachedTabBarController];
                break;
            case 2:
                //Sign up
                [cachedTabBarController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tabBarToSignup" sender:cachedTabBarController];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        //Release tab bar controller from memory
        cachedTabBarController = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

Then i wired it up to my appDelegate in applicationDidFinishLaunching...

```
//Hook up tab bar delegate
    mainTabController = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    mainTabBarDelegate = [[TabBarDelegate alloc] init];
    mainTabController.delegate = mainTabBarDelegate;
```

And Voila

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So I have part of a solution.

It only works in situations where you can choose a custom segue (and I've only written code for pushing, not modal).

Protocol "UIViewControllerAuthentication" for all controllers that require authentication, this protocol contains an method to retrieve the required authentication status.

```
enum authenticationStatus {
notLoggedIn = 0,
noPassword = 1,
loggedIn = 2
};

@protocol UIViewControllerAuthentication <NSObject>

-(enum authenticationStatus)authStatusRequired;

@end
```

Controllers that require authentication conform to this protocol:

```
-(enum authenticationStatus)authStatusRequired{
return loggedIn;
}
```

Then use this for the authenticated push segue

```
@interface SeguePushWithAuth : UIStoryboardSegue

@end
-(void)perform{
    NSLog(@"custom segue destination : %@",self.destinationViewController);
    NSLog(@"custom segue source : %@",self.sourceViewController);
    NSLog(@"custom segue dest conforms to protocol : %i",[self.destinationViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIViewControllerAuthentication)]);

    if([self.destinationViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIViewControllerAuthentication)]){
        UIViewController <UIViewControllerAuthentication> *destination = (UIViewController <UIViewControllerAuthentication> *)self.destinationViewController;
        if (!((int)[AccountModel userAuthStatus] >= (int)[destination authStatusRequired])) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authentication" message:@"You need an account to access this area" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Login",@"Create Account", nil];
            //alert
            [alert show];
            return;
        }
    }

    [[self.sourceViewController navigationController] pushViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:true];
}

@end
```

Then use custom segues in uistoryboard

This is a good pattern to allow the destination controller to cancel the segue.
However its far from what I want as I want to be able to authenticate segues that link tab bar controllers to their children.