# UITabBarController custom action with Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I would like to prompt a user to sign in with a UIAlertView when the user presses a certain tab bar item in a tab bar controller.

This tab bar controller exists in storyboard, and as a result I'm not sure where i can do this. Apple claims that UITabBarController shouldn't be subclassed, further adding to my confusion. And furthermore, i am aware of UITabBarController's delegate pattern but i don't know what view controller i can hook it up to Note: My UITabBarController is generated from a modal segue from a UIViewController.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this when answering another of my own questions, [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10344863/828859)

I used the uitabbarcontrollerdelegate and set that in the root controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can display your alert view when the selected view controller is displayed... Say you have a `LoginViewController` in the tab bar. inside that class create a method

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```

which displays the alert view

Also look at the UITabBarDelegate

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;
```

Comment: The point is to avoid that. So that i don't have to keep state of which controller i came from in case they don't log in and all the delegation around that. It's also confusing for the user. It makes more sense to have it displayed before changing views